# Installing OTRS on DreamHost

Tags: apache, debian, dreamhost, issue-tracking, otrs

I'm using a Debian VPS on DreamHost and wanted to install a feature-rich customer issue-tracking system (not for software development like Bugzilla).  OTRS made my shortlist and I followed the [Installation Instructions](http://wiki.otterhub.org/index.php?title=Installation_on_Debian_5.04_lenny) through the "Web Server Configuration" step (/etc/init.d/apache2 restart), but the restart step reported failure.  Nevertheless pgrep apache showed it was running.  In fact, it turned out that although www.mysite/otrs/installer.pl was running, my regular website showed a page claiming it had no content (but when I looked in the website's folder, its content was fine, just not being served).

DreamHost Support was very helpful, but explained that they don't use the standard Debian Apache server for hosting websites and instead use their own.  Specifically, the Debian server is in /etc/apache2, but the DreamHost server is in /dh/apache2.  DreamHost Support determined that the OTRS installation instructions were configuring the usual Debian Apache location which somehow prioritized that server instead of the DreamHost server.   They tried moving the otrs.conf file into /dh/apache2, but though the regular website was working again, the OTRS page wasn't.

Has anybody had success installing OTRS on a DreamHost VPS?

Answer (score 1):

I've consulted one of our admins on this, and these are our suggestions:

You will either need to:

1. Adapt DreamHost's Apache build to incorporate the OTRS modifications
2. Get Debian Apache up and running

Both options will require an admin user and some knowledge of Linux command line and Apache management tools. You will also need to set your VPS to UNMANAGED, which means that any changes in the DH Web Panel to any of your domains will have no effect whatsoever. Just make sure the DNS records for any domains are pointing to your server. You will also need to be able to manage your own Apache configurations.

NOTE: This will also essentially mean that DreamHost support cannot and will not troubleshoot your domains. Unmanaged means unsupported in any way!

There are a few core differences between DreamHost's apache2 configuration and the default Debian build. The first issue I observe is that DreamHost's configuration does not allow for extra configuration files to be loaded in the manner that the OTRS documentation suggests. This means if choosing option 1, you will need to manually insert the OTRS directives into DreamHost's configuration files, which may prove difficult.

I would recommend moving or otherwise disabling the /dh folder entirely after setting your VPS to unmanaged. This will not allow DH-default Apache to start when the VPS starts. You may also need to remove the DH Apache startup script in /etc/rc3.d/S02httpd2 and the actual script at /etc/init.d/httpd2.

Once you have your own version of Apache running successfully, you might consider copying the VirtualHosts that were previously at /dh/apache2/apache2-ps/etc/httpd.conf into your own domain configuration files in your conf.d directory, or you can shuffle your website files around and configure your Apache to your desire.

Once you've got your own flavor of Apache running, you should be able to implement the OTRS instructions per their wiki. :)

Comment: Well dreamhost shouldn't be responsible to troubleshoot your domains but they should be responsible to have either a "normal" version of apache available or switched to when going to unmanaged server or at least adequate documentation on what the customer needs to do when switching to unmanaged, you can't just leave customers there hanging because you use a non standard setup... especially when there's no mention of it anywhere when you sign up... anyways before my frustration kicks in... I've turned the server to unmanaged, i've disabled the startup scripts, i've moved the dh folder but still